# Fourier transform covariance estimator

Tags: covariance, variance, covariance-estimation

I am estimating realized variance and covariance by the estimator described in [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1890.pdf) paper, and relying on Fourier Transform.

Now, as my data is one day of data in ultra high frequency, so that the estimation takes time, I sample the data every minute but still use that estimator, cutting the frequencies after 100.

I have some confusion : can you confirm that by applying that paper I am calculating the daily realized variance, and that the result should be comparable to what I find if I simply sum the squared minute returns for the day?